# Resolve URLs in HTML Files

Tags: webpack

Currently I use gulp to move my Template Files from a src Folder to the template folder of the CMS (Craft), I'm aware of the copy-webpack-plugin to get the same result but it seems like that doesn't resolve URLs in the Templates.

What I would like to achieve is that Asset URLs (e.g. Images) would be resolved by webpack and their paths are written in the templates.

It would be awesome if I could write something like this `<img src="~Src/images/svg/single/logo.svg" alt="">` (`Src` is an alias configured in webpack) as I do in CSS and webpack would copy the SVG (or any other filetype) to the dist folder and insert the correct path `<img src="assets/images/svg/single/logo.svg" alt="">`

If anybody know if that is possible by any chance please let me know :)